# karate - Complex JSON schema validation does not work as expected

Tags: karate

I have been trying to validate JSON schema using Karate for our project.

After doing a bit of research I have found few pointers matching what I am looking after:

- [karate : Complex JSON Schema matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49231115/karate-complex-json-schema-matching)
- https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/346

However, trying the suggested solution against latest karate framework version - **1.4.1.RC3**, It seems there is still an issue.

Please refer below feature file and error output.

Can I request to please help us in finding the correct solution for this case?

```
Feature: JSON Schema validation

Background:
    * def json =
    """
    {
      "foo": {
        "bars": [
          { "barOne": "dc", "barTwos": [] },
          { "barOne": "dc", "barTwos": [{ title: 'blah' }] },
          { "barOne": "dc", "barTwos": [{ title: 'blah' }] },
          { "barOne": "dc", "barTwos": [{ title: 'blah' }] }
        ]
      }
    }
    """
    
    * def barTwo = { title: '#string' }
    * def bar = 
        """
            { barOne: '#string', barTwos: '##[] barTwo' }
        """
    
    Scenario: Validate JSON Schema
    * match json.foo.bars == '#[] bar'
```

**Error:**

> match failed: EQUALS
> $ | match each failed at index 0 (LIST:MAP)
> [{"barOne":"dc","barTwos":[]},{"barOne":"dc","barTwos":[{"title":"blah"}]},{"barOne":"dc","barTwos":[{"title":"blah"}]},{"barOne":"dc","barTwos":[{"title":"blah"}]}]
> {"barOne":"#string","barTwos":"##[] barTwo"}

```
$[0] | not equal | match failed for name: 'barTwos' (MAP:MAP)
{"barOne":"dc","barTwos":[]}
{"barOne":"#string","barTwos":"##[] barTwo"}

  $[0].barTwos | match each failed, empty array / list (LIST:MAP)
  []
  {"title":"#string"}
```

Considering this bug - https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/346 had been fixed in karate framework **v0.8.0** already, We would have thought it should work out of the box in latest karate framework **1.4.1.RC3**

Answer (score 0):

See if 1.4.1.RC2 works. RC3 has a change related to this issue that is still being discussed: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2364

Comment: Thanks a lot @Peter-thomas for your reply and considering it to be worked upon in future releases. Much appreciated!!!!